# Array is not able to display in CI

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

Here is my php code:-

```
Array
(
    [cus] => Anand Roy
    [depart] => science>
    [add1] => sdfrfrferwfrfrfeferv
    [add2] => veververv eververv
    [cty] => Jalpaiguri
    [pin] => 735101
    [st] => West Bengal
    [em] => cosmilisation@gmail.com
    [tele] => 919641758183
    [fax] => 
    [admin] => uh
    [aphn] => 919641758183
    [bill] => khkj
    [bphn] => 919641758183
    [key] => khkj
    [kphn] => 919641758183
    [am] => 1 am
    [pm] => 1 pm
    [week] => 
)
```

I m unable to display their data in view....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data['myarray']=Array
(
[cus] => Anand Roy
[depart] => science
[add1] => sdfrfrferwfrfrfeferv
[add2] => veververv eververv
[cty] => Jalpaiguri
[pin] => 735101
[st] => West Bengal
[em] => cosmilisation@gmail.com
[tele] => 919641758183
[fax] => 
[admin] => uh
[aphn] => 919641758183
[bill] => khkj
[bphn] => 919641758183
[key] => khkj
[kphn] => 919641758183
[am] => 1 am
[pm] => 1 pm
[week] => 
);   // initialize your array 
$this->load->view("viewfile",$data);   // pass the array to your view page
```

And in your viewfile, access it like :

```
foreach($myarray as $array)   // foreach array elements
{
   echo $array['cus'];          // echo it based on array index
}
```

Comment: $this->load->view("viewfile",$data); ?

Comment: try https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Comment: @RakeshSharma..If we need to pass to another controller's view file then we have to specify the controller/view folder name.

Comment: not make sense you can't load view using controller name you need to only viewname or if view/myview/myview.php then $this->load->view("myview/myview",$data);

Comment: yes..Both names are same no..User controller will have view folder user. Sorry if it was mistaken :)

Comment: your welcome :) looks great effort on stack from past mnths

Comment: try printing the array in view file with `print_r($myarray);`